# Library overriding issue in Gradle for multiple projects

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, gradle

I use Android Studio. I need to make two applications work together. The issue is that both of them use Google Maps API. First app uses API v 8.3.0 and the other one uses much older (I don't know the exact version, but the library is in .jar, which google used for previous versions).

When I build a single project, without importing "tracker", everything is ok. But when I add second project, I get next error:

```
Error:(91, 17) error: cannot find symbol method getMapAsync(<anonymous OnMapReadyCallback>)
```

The problem line is:

```
((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview_location))
                .getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                        map = googleMap;
                        onMapGot();
                    }
                });
```

How can I fix this problem?

Here is the dependencies of my main project Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:+"
    compile files('libs/splunk-mint-4.2.1.jar')
    compile project(':vksdk_library')
    compile project(':odnoklassniki-android-sdk')
    compile project(':viewpager_library')
    compile project(':tracker') //second project


    compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:+'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:+'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
}
```

And here is for my subproject, which I imported as module:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':SlidingMenu')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: I dont think your `google-play-services.jar` contains the method `getMapAsync` because it newly added, so you need newer google play service library.

Comment: The problem is that google-play-services.jar is present in second project, where it is necessary to use this version. But for unknown reasons gradle tries to use this library in first project too (where I import latest google services)

Comment: change the order? First compile 8.3 then compile the second project. Or use the `exclude` in gradle, check here:https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-exclude-transitive-dependency/2119/3

Comment: just change the order in dependencies, i am guessing, but might not work, i suggest u check the `exclude` tag in gradle

Comment: Changing order didn't help, what about exclude - I tried it in different variations, unfortunately it didn't help. I get exception - Gradle DSL method not found: 'exclude()'

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html